# SQL JOIN Multiple Tables & Get AVG

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to do a couple of JOINS in my sql query but have run into a problem. What i need to do is select all fields from the `poker_sites` table then grab 2 relative fields from `networks` and if it is available get the average rating from `editor_content`

The problem i am having is the query is only returning one row when there should be at least three.

Any help would be much appreciated.

here is my SQL

```
SELECT AVG(editor_content.rating) AS rating, poker_sites.*,
networks.network_name, networks.network_icon FROM poker_sites
    LEFT JOIN networks
    ON (poker_sites.network_id=networks.network_id)
    LEFT JOIN editor_content
    ON (poker_sites.site_id=editor_content.assign_id)
    WHERE poker_sites.published=1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need GROUP BY if you want to get multiple results with an aggregate function (in this case AVG).

```
    SELECT x.avgRating AS rating, poker_sites.*,
        networks.network_name, networks.network_icon 
    FROM poker_sites
    LEFT JOIN networks
        ON (poker_sites.network_id=networks.network_id)
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT AVG(editor_content.rating) as avgRating, editor_content.assign_id
        FROM editor_content
        GROUP BY editor_content.assign_id
    ) x
        ON (poker_sites.site_id = x.assign_id)
    WHERE poker_sites.published=1
```